# Removing mouseclick and adding border to simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseover

Greetings and thanks in advance for the help.  My first hack at javascript. Just trying to add a 2em black border around the slider, and remove the mouse pointer when hovering over the slider (I don't wish to offer links from the pictures).

Link is: www.bakashana.org/test-slider

Here is the entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
<!--

var slideimages=new Array()
function slideshowimages(){
for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
slideimages[i]=new Image()
slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
}
}
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>
<center><a href="javascript:slideshowimages()"><img src="https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-girls-jump-compressor-400x300_c.jpg" name="slide" border="2em" width=400 height=300></a></center>
<script>
<!--

//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links
slideshowimages("https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-girls-jump-compressor-400x300_c.jpg","https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/All-the-ladies-compressor-400x300_c.jpg","https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/highcompress-banner20-400x300_c.jpg","https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/banner10-1-compressor-400x300_c.jpg","https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.163/4b5.320.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/cropped-banner-testing-compressor-400x300_c.jpg")

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=2000

var whichimage=0
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
whichlink=whichimage
if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
whichimage++
else
whichimage=0
setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()

//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HE Ibnelaiq, thanks for taking time to look this over.  As stated above, I want to add a 2em black border around the slider, and remove the mouse pointer when hovering over the slider

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet.  My Apologies, I am new with Javascript and haven't figured out how to nest this code in with the previous code:  specifically: in what order this code combines with the original code, and what goes in the head vs. the body.  Sorry to be so novice, it would be a huge help if you could show the entire page, so i can learn how everything comes together.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help!  I tried the abovementioned solutions but wasn't able to get them to work properly (the mouse hand continued to be seen on scroll-over).  I found the easiest possible solution, I thought I would post it for others to see.

```
<style>
#yourSlider{
    width:400px !important;
    height:300px !important;
    border:.2em solid black;
    pointer-events:none !important;

}
</style>
```

The 'pointer-events:none !important' taking care of the scroll-over issue (it didn't work without the !important added), and the border taking care of the border issue.

Thanks again to all who contributed!

Answer (score 0):

Okay this as you mentioned in comment so there it is. Removing cursor with simple CSS:By adding `cursor:none` property to slider and using pseudo class `:hover` to checking if the cursor is hovering the given div and then apply `border` property to it on other hand disabling the mouse clicks on your slider like this but we need to use jquery for this i have added the jquery in snippet working example below.

```js
 var event = $("#yourSlider").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});

// disable right click
$("#yourSlider").bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

```css
#yourSlider{
    background:orange;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    cursor:none;
}
#yourSlider:hover{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourSlider"></div>
```

Comment: It supports hover just fine after fixing capitalization of `#yourSlider:hover`

Comment: Yeah. just a minor mistake .

Comment: Removed blockquote